# How to get all the elements of a WPF TreeView as a List?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I need to access the nodes of a TreeView as a plain list (as if all the nodes where expanded) to be able to do multiselection pressing the Shift key. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: what about http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24585/WPF-MultiSelect-TreeView-Sample

Comment: @Klaus78: this document does not talk about Shift selection at all ... :(

Comment: in the article the multiselect is implemented with left ctrl key. It should not be that hard to adapt the code for a multiselect with shift key.

Comment: How are you populating the TreeView? Are you using a HeirachicalDataTemplate?

Comment: @Klaus78: the behavior of multiselection in a control is completely different is you use Ctrl or Shift. For sure you know that. And yes, the selection is pretty different.

Comment: @nmaait: yes, I'm using HierarchucalDataTemplates.

Comment: Can you post the code of your DataSource?

Comment: I need to use the TreeViewItems as this is a generic control and I cannot rely on a specific DataSource

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a method that will retrieve all the TreeViewItems in a TreeView. Please be aware that this is an extremely expensive method to run, as it will have to expand all TreeViewItems nodes and perform an updateLayout each time. As the TreeViewItems are only created when expanding the parent node, there is no other way to do that.

If you only need the list of the nodes that are already opened, you can remove the code that expand them, it will then be much cheaper.

Maybe you should try to find another way to manage multiselection. Having said that, here is the method :

```
    public static List<TreeViewItem> FindTreeViewItems(this Visual @this)
    {
        if (@this == null)
            return null;

        var result = new List<TreeViewItem>();

        var frameworkElement = @this as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement != null)
        {
            frameworkElement.ApplyTemplate();
        }

        Visual child = null;
        for (int i = 0, count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(@this); i < count; i++)
        {
            child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(@this, i) as Visual;

            var treeViewItem = child as TreeViewItem;
            if (treeViewItem != null)
            {
                result.Add(treeViewItem);
                if (!treeViewItem.IsExpanded)
                {
                    treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;
                    treeViewItem.UpdateLayout();
                }
            }
            foreach (var childTreeViewItem in FindTreeViewItems(child))
            {
                result.Add(childTreeViewItem);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: To improve this code even more, you can add a condition to make sure the TreeViewItem contains items before expanding.

                if (treeViewItem.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (!treeViewItem.IsExpanded)
                    {
                        treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;
                        treeViewItem.UpdateLayout();
                    }
                }

Answer (score -3):

Here is what you asked;

```
private static TreeViewItem[] getTreeViewItems(TreeView treeView)
{
    List<TreeViewItem> returnItems = new List<TreeViewItem>();
    for (int x = 0; x < treeView.Items.Count; x++)
    {
        returnItems.AddRange(getTreeViewItems((TreeViewItem)treeView.Items[x]));
    }
    return returnItems.ToArray();
}
private static TreeViewItem[] getTreeViewItems(TreeViewItem currentTreeViewItem)
{
    List<TreeViewItem> returnItems = new List<TreeViewItem>();
    returnItems.Add(currentTreeViewItem);
    for (int x = 0; x < currentTreeViewItem.Items.Count; x++)
    {
        returnItems.AddRange(getTreeViewItems((TreeViewItem)currentTreeViewItem.Items[x]));
    }
    return returnItems.ToArray();
}
```

Call with your control as the first parameter e.g.;

```
getTreeViewItems(treeView1);
```

Comment: As far as I know treeView.Items returns the items of the treeview (the real content) not the treeviewitems. If you populate the treeview with objects Folder then treeviewItems returns a list of Folder objects.