# Change the value of a custom Dependency Property programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to change the value of a custom Dependency Property programmatically.

This is my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style
            x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle"
            TargetType="TreeViewItem">    
            <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger
                  Property="local:ColorHelper.IsColor"
                  Value="True" >
               <Setter
                  Property="Foreground"
                  Value="{Binding Color}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger
                  Property="local:ColorHelper.IsColor"
                  Value="False" >
               <Setter
                  Property="Foreground"
                  Value="Black" />
               </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Window.Resources>
```

I want this style to be applied to a treeview

```
<TreeView
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           Margin="15,65,15,0"
           x:Name="treeView1"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
           Grid.RowSpan="2"
           Grid.Column="1" />
```

And changing the color value of the IsColor property through a checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
                     Name="CHK_Gray"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Foreground="DarkGray"
                     Grid.Row="6"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Grid.RowSpan="1"
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                     Unchecked="grayCheckBox_Unchecked"
                     Checked="grayCheckBox_Checked">
                     Show Created Assembly (in Grey)
                  </CheckBox>
```

The Dependency Property is created like this:

```
 public class ColorHelper : DependencyObject
   {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty IsColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "IsColor", typeof(bool), typeof(ColorHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false));


      public static void SetIsColor(DependencyObject target, Boolean value)
      {
         target.SetValue(IsColorProperty, value);
      }

      public static bool GetIsColor(DependencyObject target)
      {
         return (bool)target.GetValue(IsColorProperty);
      }
   }
```

How can i do in the Checked and Unchecked event to change the value of the IsColor property?

```
private void grayCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     ???
  }
  private void grayCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     ???
  }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: why do you use code-behind for this task? use Triggers `<Style.Triggers><Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True"><Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/></Trigger> <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False"><Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MyColor}"/></Trigger>`

Comment: The Foreground Property is for a TreeView and the CheckBox is external

Comment: make a proper [mcve] in that case

Comment: @ASh i modified the question because i'm trying to follow your suggestion and using triggers. I hope there are all the informations needed. Could you please help me with this problem..? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to the element of which you want to set the attached property to begin with.

You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382125/7252182) method to get the `TreeViewItem` elements of the `TreeView` and then set the property of all of them if that's that you want:

```
foreach(TreeViewItem tvi i tv.FindTreeViewItems())
    ColorHelper.SetIsColor(tvi, true);
```

Note that you cannot edit the *template* programmatically. And even if you could, it wouldn't really help as it has already been applied to the actual elements.